# The difference between module importing in webpack bunde size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, es6-modules

The question is what's the difference between these two:

```
import { ModalHeader, ModalBody } from 'reactstrap';
```

and:

```
import ModalHeader from 'reactstrap/lib/ModalHeader';
import ModalBody from 'reactstrap/lib/ModalBody';
```

Does it make any difference in webpack bundle size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just test it yourself to see if the size differs

Comment: I believe, tree shaking is not possible with second option. But I'm not sure if there is tree shaking in your webpack config. If you are gonna test it, better test it with production mode

Comment: That depends on how `reactstrap` is implemented. If it is just re-exporting those items, (and not having any side effects), it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Lodash, the second option is appeared to be ~30% less bundle size than the first one. I would guess it is only depending on how tree shaking is implemented by library developers, but it seems that, in the first case, some additional basic code also ends up in the bundle hence the first case is a little bit bigger in size. I assume in case of `reactstrap` it should be somewhere similar

Hope this helps :)